# Timestamp in postgresql during oracle to postgresql migration

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Oracle with timestamp data in `"JAN-16-15 05.10.14.034000000 PM"`.
When I created the table in postgresql with "col_name timestamp" it is showing data as "`2015-01-16 17:10:14.034`".

Any suggestions on how can set the column to get the data format as in postgre same to what I have in Oracle?

Comment: This is my timstamp in the database. Do I have to set something on database level in postgresql ----------db=> select current_timestamp;
       current_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2019-03-22 13:40:55.482237+00

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps (or dates or numbers) do **not** have any "format2. Neither in Postgres nor in Oracle or in any other relational database).

Any "format" you see, is applied by your SQL client *displaying* those values.

You need to configure your SQL client to use a different format for timestamp, or use the `to_char()` function to format the value as you want.

In particular, to get the format you desire, use

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'MON-MM-YY HH.MI.SS.US000 AM');
```

---

The output format can be changed in `psql` by changing the [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) parameter, but I would strongly recommend to **not** change it away from the default ISO format as that also affects the input that is parsed.